# SNMP requests timeout on Specific OID

Tags: snmp, timeout

I´m trying to perform a SNMPBulkWalk on a Device, but it will always run into an Timeout on a the same OID.

When I try a SNMPGetNext on the OID before it also runs into an timeout.

Requests:

`snmpbulkwalk -Cr10 -v2c -c *** -t 10 -r 5 IP OID`

I already increasead and deacreased the parameters.

Comment: Sounds like that SNMP agent has a bug when responding to that specific OID. You can only escalate to the device vendor for assistance.

Comment: If you add specifics (device model/version, exact OIDs involved, output of failing commands, etc), maybe you will get help here.

Comment: Also firmware update may solve the problem. Although in some cases I'd rather avoid triggering the bug instead.